# Twig template trying to render itself in an infinite loop (Symfony2 app)

Tags: php, symfony, twig

The web profiler bar that should render at the bottom of the screen is throwing a "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached" error because it's stuck in an infinite loop trying to load the same template file in generated code.

Here are the two lines of code that cause the infinite loop.

```
0.5359    7623912  96. __TwigTemplate_12d25e382d980637bca9380c409ddd59->__construct(???) /var/www/site/app/cache/dev/classes.php:7999
0.5359    7624296  97. Twig_Environment->loadTemplate(???, ???) /var/www/site/app/cache/dev/twig/12/d2/5e382d980637bca9380c409ddd59.php:10
```

I checked the source code, and it seems the same Twig template is loading itself in its constructor. I've included snippets of the source for these two files below. I'm sure I need to include more, but I'm not sure what to include.

app/cache/dev/classes.php

```
public function loadTemplate($name, $index = null)
{
    $cls = $this->getTemplateClass($name, $index);
    if (isset($this->loadedTemplates[$cls])) {
        return $this->loadedTemplates[$cls];
    }
    if (!class_exists($cls, false)) {
        if (false === $cache = $this->getCacheFilename($name)) {
            eval('?>'.$this->compileSource($this->loader->getSource($name), $name));
        } else {
            if (!is_file($cache) || ($this->isAutoReload() && !$this->isTemplateFresh($name, filemtime($cache)))) {
                $this->writeCacheFile($cache, $this->compileSource($this->loader->getSource($name), $name));
            }
            require_once $cache;
        }
    }
    if (!$this->runtimeInitialized) {
        $this->initRuntime();
    }
    return $this->loadedTemplates[$cls] = new $cls($this); // CALLS THE CONSTRUCTOR BELOW
}
```

app/cache/dev/twig/12/d2/5e382d980637bca9380c409ddd59.php

```
public function __construct(Twig_Environment $env)
{
    parent::__construct($env);

    $this->parent = $this->env->loadTemplate("WebProfilerBundle:Profiler:layout.html.twig"); // CALLS THE loadTemplate METHOD ABOVE

    $this->blocks = array(
        'body' => array($this, 'block_body'),
        'panel' => array($this, 'block_panel'),
    );
}
```

Comment: maybe a `php app/console cache:clear` would help? (sometimes things aren't cached 100% correct which can lead to unexpected errors)

Comment: I've manually deleted app/cache/* many times, but cache:clear errors out from the same infinite recursion via: 
Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php:105
Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/CacheWarmer/CacheWarmerAggregate.php:47
Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/CacheWarmer/TemplateCacheCacheWarmer.php:62

Comment: maybe you have infinite loop in your teplate directly? (eg. include statament to itself) Could you show the template?

Comment: Did you try to increase the nesting limit? This is a common error when using xdebug (which sets it to 100). 200 usually solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to comment so I am posting this as a solution. Sorry.

Sometimes certain redirect or rewrite rules defined in server configuration or htaccess causes infinite rewrites or redirects. I would suggest modifying your routes like changing

```
/foo/bar/1
```

to

```
/foo/bar/1/
```

Or, try examining your redirect or rewrite rules. I am sure you will catch up something if you are 100% certain that your code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I came across the same issue recently.

I tried clearing my cache, increasing my xdebug limit, and I checked for circular includes in my twig files, but none of that helped.

For me, the solution was to make sure that I was loading a stable version of twig in my `composer.json` file, by adding the following code to my require section:

```
"twig/twig": "@stable"
```

Comment: where can I find the composer.json file?

Comment: Assuming that you installed your dependencies with composer, it should be at the root of your project